# Redmine, error on bundle exec rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine

I'm trying to install redmine version 3.1.1 and "production bundle exec rake db:create" creates the database nicely, but "production bundle exec rake db:migrate" throws error.

I'm following this guide: http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineInstall

Rails version: Rails 4.2.4

My database.yml is

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: redmine_default
  host: localhost
  port: 5432
  username: redmine_default
  password: "pass#2015" 
  encoding: utf8
```

Here's my console response.

```
user@user:~/redmine-3.1.1$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:create
iapo@iapo:~/redmine-3.1.1/config$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate
(in /home/iapo/redmine-3.1.1)
DEPRECATION WARNING: You did not specify a `log_level` in `production.rb`. Currently, the default value for `log_level` is `:info` for the production
environment and `:debug` in all other environments. In Rails 5 the default value will be unified to `:debug` across all environments. To preserve 
the current setting, add the following line to your `production.rb`:

   config.log_level = :info

. (called from block in tsort_each at /home/iapo/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- awesome_nested_set
/home/iapo/redmine-3.1.1/config/initializers/10-patches.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/iapo/redmine-3.1.1/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

*// with trace*

```
user@user:~/redmine-3.1.1/config$ RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:migrate --trace
(in /home/user/redmine-3.1.1)
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
DEPRECATION WARNING: You did not specify a `log_level` in `production.rb`. Currently, the default value for `log_level` is `:info` for the production
environment and `:debug` in all other environments. In Rails 5 the default value will be unified to `:debug` across all environments. To preserve 
the current setting, add the following line to your `production.rb`:

   config.log_level = :info

. (called from block in tsort_each at /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226)
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- awesome_nested_set
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/redmine-3.1.1/config/initializers/10-patches.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:420:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:429:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:419:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `call'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:413:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tsort.rb:203:in `tsort_each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
/home/user/redmine-3.1.1/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

Comment: try to run command from the project root. I mean `~/redmine-3.1.1` not from `~/redmine-3.1.1/config`

Comment: Still got the same error.

Comment: Moved to root directory `/redmine-3.1.1` and run `bundle exec rake db:migrate`

Comment: Still got the same error.

Comment: I't is and permission error, I tried with root and it worked, my i did chown on all files.

Comment: yes, all gems (`bundle install`) should run NOT under root user!